# Schema export with hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, orm, hbm2ddl

I'm using hibernate annotations and i want to export my database schema.

Similar to the schemaexporttask with hbm xml files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the original Hibernate Core `SchemaExportTask` can only handle Hibernate XML mapping files, not annotations. What you need is the `HibernateToolTask` that comes with [Hibernate Tools](http://tools.hibernate.org/).

Here is an Usage example adapted from Java Persistence With Hibernate:

```
<taskdef name="hibernatetool"
         classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask"
         classpathref="project.classpath"/>
  <target name="schemaexport" depends="compile, copymetafiles"
          description="Exports a generated schema to DB and file">
    <hibernatetool destdir="${basedir}">
      <classpath path="${build.dir}"/>
      <configuration 
          configurationfile="${build.dir}/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
      <hbm2ddl
          drop="true"
          create="true"
          export="true"
          outputfilename="helloworld-ddl.sql"
          delimiter=";"
          format="true"/>
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

#### See also

- [Hibernate 3 Annotations & Ant](http://gorillajawn.com/wordpress/2007/07/31/hibernate-3-annotations-ant/)

Answer (score 11):

**You can**. Just do it

```
AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();

configuration
.addAnnotatedClass(<TYPE_YOUR_CLASS>.class)
.setProperty(Environment.USER, <TYPE_YOUR_USER>)
.setProperty(Environment.PASS, <TYPE_YOUR_PASSWORD>)
.setProperty(Environment.URL, <TYPE_YOUR_URL>)
.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, <TYPE_YOUR_DIALECT>)
.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, <TYPE_YOUR_DRIVER>);

SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(configuration);
schema.setOutputFile("schema.sql");

schema.create(<DO_YOU_WANT_TO_PRINT_TO_THE_CONSOLE>, <DO_YOU_WANT_TO_EXPORT_THE_SCRIPT_TO_THE_DATABASE>);
```

Comment: This looks interesting.  Do i need any extra libraries for this ?

Comment: @Anthony No, It is bundled with Hibernate

Comment: What is the preferred solution for Hibernate 3.5+?

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is interested how to do this with JPA+Spring from a unit test (you can generate the sql running the unit test from inside Eclipse like a breeze):

ExportDatabaseSchema.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
public class ExportDatabaseSchema {

  @Resource(name="&entityManagerFactory")
  private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

  @Test
  public void exportDatabaseSchema(){
    PersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnitInfo = entityManagerFactory.getPersistenceUnitInfo();
    Map jpaPropertyMap = entityManagerFactory.getJpaPropertyMap();

    Configuration configuration = new Ejb3Configuration().configure( persistenceUnitInfo, jpaPropertyMap ).getHibernateConfiguration();

    SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(configuration);
    schema.setOutputFile("resources/sql/schema.sql");
    schema.create(false, false);
  }
}
```

You need an ExportDatabaseSchema-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-jpa.xml" /> 
</beans>
```

The applicationContext-jpa.xml contains the annotation configured entityManagerFactory bean. The trick is to inject it with & like this: "&entityManagerFactory", to dereference the spring generated proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Use hibernate3-maven-plugin. Then run 'mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl'