# Exporting DDL schema in Hibernate using model classes with annotation and ANT

Tags: hibernate, ant, annotations, schema, ddl

I am having my model classes with annotation.
We need to create schema sql using those classes. but can not find any way to do that.
there are many threads on stackoverflow regarding this, but none of them working for me.

one of the thread is [Schema export with hibernate annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393092/schema-export-with-hibernate-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-test-sql-scripts</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <property name="maven_test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath"/>
                    <path id="hibernate_tools_path">
                        <pathelement path="${maven_test_classpath}"/>
                    </path>
                    <property name="hibernate_tools_classpath" refid="hibernate_tools_path"/>
                    <taskdef name="hibernatetool"
                             classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask"/>
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/hsqldb"/>
                    <hibernatetool destdir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/hsqldb">
                        <classpath refid="hibernate_tools_path"/>
                        <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="testPersistenceUnit"
                                          propertyfile="src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"/>
                        <hbm2ddl drop="false" create="true" export="false"
                                 outputfilename="create_db.sql"
                                 delimiter=";" format="true"/>
                        <hbm2ddl drop="true" create="false" export="false"
                                 outputfilename="drop_db.sql"
                                 delimiter=";" format="true"/>
                    </hibernatetool>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.tools.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I had tried similar one using ANT, but that was not working with hibernate mapping in classes (using annotations).

Comment: I have both JPA and Hibernate annotations and it works.